# Directive 'safe_mode' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, deprecated

I have got this error `PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'safe_mode' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0` when I have updated my hosting `PHP` version from `5.6` to `7.2`

how can I solve this problem or I must contact my hosting provider ?!

here is my `php.ini` setting file found in my mean path

```
; cPanel-generated PHP ini directives, do not edit
; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
; For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M
max_execution_time = 36000
upload_max_filesize = 999M
safe_mode = On;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.auto_start = Off;
session.use_only_cookies = On;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = On;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600
allow_url_fopen = On
display_errors = On
;error_reporting = E_ALL;
allow_url_include = On
enable_dl = On
file_uploads = On
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
post_max_size = 8M
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea3"
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

Comment: Remove the line `safe_mode = On;` -- this setting no longer exists (read the 3rd line from the top to find out where you can edit this file).

Comment: The file itself also claims you can edit from C-Panel, so you can try turning it off there if you like.

Comment: @rickdenhaan thank you, and i have comment out this line as `;safe_mode = On;` but still getting the same error ... do you think i should ask my hosting to restart the server!

Comment: If you didn't edit it via CPanel, then yes. Any change to `php.ini` are applied when the webserver software (Apache, Nginx, whatever your hosting provider is using) is restarted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should read up on [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php). In the docs, will see that:

> **Warning**:  This feature has been *DEPRECATED* as of PHP 5.3.0 and *REMOVED* as of PHP 5.4.0.

Second, you can get the error to go away by removing this line:

```
safe_mode = On;
```

**NOTE**: You must be certain to find the correct INI file. Some operating systems or methods of installing PHP will have a separate php.ini file for the web server and Command Line Interface (CLI). For example, on my ubuntu workstation, I have one for apache and one for CLI:

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

To find out what INI file you should edit, I suggest looking at the output of `phpinfo()` and looking at the value for **Loaded Configuration File**. To do that on a web server, use this file:

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

If you want to find out where the php.ini file is for CLI scripts, you can use this command:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

If you are make changes to the ini file for your web server, you'll need to restart the web server for this change to take effect. On Ubuntu or other debian-based distros, you might do that with a command like so:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You may need to tweak that command, depending on distro, distro version, apache version, etc. I believe that for CentOS or Red Hat-based distros, one of these should work:

```
sudo service httpd restart
sudo apachectl restart
```

**NOTE**: If your machine is configured to use **php-fpm** for handling PHP requests, then things work differently for your web server. Your system will maintain a process pool of PHP processes entirely separate from your web server. You will need to restart the PHP process pool. The command to accomplish that varies widely depending on the distro and your version of PHP. Check [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-reload-restart-php7-0-fpm-service-linux-unix/) for your distro and see if you can find one that works.

For CLI invocations of PHP, the changes should take effect each time you run a new php script. You shouldn't have to restart anything for new commands to see the changes you made. If you have some long-running PHP script for some reason (very unusual) then you'd need to halt that process and re-invoke it after making your INI changes.

EDIT: I'd also point out that your INI file very clearly states you might get weird behavior on your CPANEL system. Make sure you follow its instructions:

```
; cPanel-generated PHP ini directives, do not edit
; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
; For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
```

Comment: i have comment out this line as `;safe_mode = On;` but still getting the same error ... do you think i need the server to get restart

Comment: Yes, you have to restart your server - only then the configuration is read

Comment: @RehamFahmy I have expanded my answer to provide more detail. I hope you find it useful enough to supply your answer.